# Cancel previous request using axios with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using `axios` and `vue.js`.I have google it,and check the axios docs but still cannot understand how to do it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> ## 2022 UPDATE

To cancel requests use [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal

axios.get('/foo/bar', { signal })
.then(function(response) {
   //...
});

// cancel the request
controller.abort()
```

**Explanation:** We first create a controller with AbortController and grab the reference to its associated [AbortSignal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) object by accessing `AbortController.signal` property.

Then to associate the signal with the request, we pass that signal as an option inside the request's options object. Then to cancel/abort the request we call `controller.abort()`.

The amazing thing about this is that we can use it in the exact same way with the fetch API:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal

fetch('/foo/bar', { signal })
.then(function(response) {
   //...
});

// cancel the request
controller.abort()
```

---

---

> Cancel token has been deprecated since v0.22.0 and shouldn't be used in new projects.

> ## 2020 UPDATE: How to cancel an axios request

#### generate a `cancelToken` and store it

```
import axios from 'axios'
const request = axios.CancelToken.source();
```

#### pass the `cancelToken` to the axios request

```
axios.get('API_URL', { cancelToken: request.token })
```

#### Access the request you stored and call the `.cancel()` method to cancel it

```
request.cancel("Optional message");
```

[See it live on a tiny app on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-cancel-request-jb7xc)

---

---

> Take a look at [axios cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

---

---

> A simple example which you can [see it live.](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-example-of-cancelling-axios-request-kyrnc?file=/src/App.vue)

**HTML:**

```html
<button @click="send">Send</button>
<button :disabled="!request" @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

**JS**

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    requests: [],
    request: null
  }),

  methods: {
    send() {
      if (this.request) this.cancel();
      this.makeRequest();
    },

    cancel() {
      this.request.cancel();
      this.clearOldRequest("Cancelled");
    },

    makeRequest() {
      const axiosSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
      this.request = { cancel: axiosSource.cancel, msg: "Loading..." };
      axios
        .get(API_URL, { cancelToken: axiosSource.token })
        .then(() => {
          this.clearOldRequest("Success");
        })
        .catch(this.logResponseErrors);
    },

    logResponseErrors(err) {
      if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("Request cancelled");
      }
    },

    clearOldRequest(msg) {
      this.request.msg = msg;
      this.requests.push(this.request);
      this.request = null;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, this example actually still tries to cancel a request even if it was completed. The answer below by @live2 makes sure the cancelToken is reset to `null` after a successful request

Comment: Robin Hoodie this cancels the previous request but not if it was completed. Did you checked out the codesandbox example ?

Comment: In the codesandbox you've provided (which contains excellent code), you're right, you can't click the cance button if the request was completed. 
I meant the example in the answer itself, there you can still call `cancel` even if the request was cancelled because the `cancel` variable is never set to `null` on completion of the request.

Comment: @Robin-Hoodie I updated my answer + the tiny app + a simple live example. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: 2022: CancelToken is deprecated. AbortController should be used now in new projects

Answer (score 16):

In this example the current request canceled when a new one starts.
The server answers after 5 seconds if a new request fired before the old one is canceled. The `cancelSource` specifies a cancel token that can be used to cancel the request. For more informations check the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      searchItems: null,
      searchText: "some value",
      cancelSource: null,
      infoText: null
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      if (this.searchText.length < 3) {
        return;
      }

      this.searchItems = null;
      this.infoText = 'please wait 5 seconds to load data';

      this.cancelSearch();
      this.cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

      axios.get(`https://httpbin.org/delay/5?search=${this.searchText}`, {
        cancelToken: this.cancelSource.token }).then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            this.searchItems = response.data;
            this.infoText = null;
            this.cancelSource = null;
          }
        });
    },
    cancelSearch () {
      if (this.cancelSource) {
        this.cancelSource.cancel('Start new search, stop active search');
        console.log('cancel request done');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="searchText" type="text" />
  <button @click="search">Search</button>{{infoText}}
  <pre>
  {{searchItems}}
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it in a Pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useSomeStore = defineStore('some', {
    state: () => ({
        someList: [],
        abortController: null,
    }),

    actions: {
        async getSomeList() {
            try {
                if (this.abortController) {
                    this.abortController.abort();
                }

                this.abortController = new AbortController();
                const signal = this.abortController.signal;

                axois.get('admin/providers/list', { signal })
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.someList = res.data.data;
                        this.abortController = null;
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        this.isFetching = false;
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error', error);
                throw error;
            }
        },
    },
});
```

The important thing is this:

```
            // step 1: if abortController is active, it means a request 
            // is in progress and we need to cancel it before proceeding
            if (this.abortController) {
                this.abortController.abort();
            }

            // step 2: abortController wasnt active, so activate one
            // and grab its signal
            this.abortController = new AbortController();
            const signal = this.abortController.signal;

            // step 3: make request and pass in signal
            await axios.get('admin/providers/list', { signal });

            // step 4: unset the abortController after request is done
            this.signalController = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

First define some variables

```
data: function () {
    return {
        request_source : ''
    }
},
```

Then inside the method

```
source = CancelToken.source();
if(this.request_source != '')
    this.request_source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');

this.request_source = source;

axios
   .get(
       URL,
          {
              params:{key1: value1},
              cancelToken: this.request_source.token
          }
    )
```